# How to use "or" with pipelines in go templates?

Tags: templates, go

How can I use the "or" operator with multiple comparison arguments or any idea where I can find some examples? There seem to be none on the [official doc](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template).

```
if (x == "value" && y == "other") || (x != "a") && (y == "b"){
  print("hello")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by multiple comparison arguments? Do you mean something like `x == 1 || x == 2`?

Answer (score 8):

The official docs [**do**](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions) have explanations for for `or`, `and`, `eq`, and `neq` for use in templates. You can read about template functions [here.](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions)

The thing to remember is that the functions provided in templates are prefix notation ([Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)). For example the not equal operator  `ne 1 2` would evaluate to true given that its two arguments 1 and 2 are not equal. Here is an [example](http://play.golang.org/p/F6fErzRMHH) of a template that uses your given expression rewritten in prefix with template functions.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Values struct {
    Title, X, Y string
}

func main() {
        // Parenthesis are used to illustrate order of operation but could be omitted
    const given_template = `
    {{ if or (and (eq .X "value") (eq .Y "other")) (and (ne .X "a") (eq .Y "b")) }}
    print("hello, {{.Title}}")
    {{end}}`

    values := []Values{
        Values{Title: "first", X: "value", Y: "other"},
        Values{Title: "second", X: "not a", Y: "b"},
        Values{Title: "neither", X: "Hello", Y: "Gopher"},
    }

    t := template.Must(template.New("example").Parse(given_template))

    for _, value := range values {
        err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, &value)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/F6fErzRMHH)